# C# JSONConvert.DeserializeObject JSON with Newlines

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have the following sample JSON in a variable called JSONContent

```
[
  {"comment":"This is \\na comment"},
  {"comment":"This is another comment"}
]
```

I type the JSON as such:

```
public class Comments
{
    [JsonProperty("comment")]
    public string comment { get; set; }
}
```

And Deserialize as such:

```
var Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Comments>>(JSONContent);
```

I then loop through the RESULT:

```
// Loop through the JSON object and populate the rows
foreach (var message in Result)
{
    doSomething( message.comment );
}
```

When I inspect the message.comment it shows as:

This is \\na comment

This is another comment

What happens later is I am saving the comment into a database but the database shows the literal "\n" in the result instead of the hopeful newline.  This is of course because c# is just converting the \\ to a literal \ and ignoring the n.

I know I can do a replace on the comment, but it feels like I am missing something that tells JSONConvert.DeserializeObject to do this for me.

Comment: Your JSON just contains an escaped backslash followed by "na". There's no newline there. Why would you expect there to be?

Comment: Aaaah, could it be the Serializer is converting the true newline to \\n.  I tested with just \n and it accepted it.  I think this is becoming clearer.